# Repairing a failed generic AC/DC power supply which "ticks"

Tags: power-supply, repair, fault

This type of death affects a lot of power supplies, Computer power supplies, Monitors, and other mains powered equipment that is stepped down to low voltage, high ampage DC.

On plugging in, the psu board makes a ticking sound (sounds a bit like static), every half second or so (but slightly irregular) - and when un-plugged the ticking slows down and stops, Assumed to be a capacitor draining.
Usually showing no obvious visual defects, no dry joints, burnt tracks, hot spots, burned out transistors etc...

What could cause a PSU board to make this ticking sound?

please note the sound refereed to sounds like static, but no arking can be seen, it is not coming from a relay. It is irregular so is highly unlikely to be a startup protection cutout.

An example of a generic PSU:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe a photograph of the PCB in the power supply area would help?

Comment: Could be arcing/breaking down somewhere. Try powering up in a dark space and watch for sparks.

Comment: I'll get a pic up asap. I'll try that too jim!

Whats with the -1??!!

Comment: I don't know about the -1, but in general repair questions are off topic.  Unless you spend time to narrow things down it's too open ended for a Q & A format. http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/2478/11861 .  A lot of modern PS's will test/attempt to power up , hit an over current limit and then cycle through a start up pattern -> one possibility for the clicking.  If that is the case, then it may not be the PSU but a failed and /or shorting main board.

Comment: Can the power supply board be powered without the main board connected?

Comment: @rawbrawb - I thought it might be useful as this is a common problem with various types of AC/DC power supply boards - many PC PSU's suffer this as well as monitors and non-computer harware.

Comment: I have edited the question to be more generic and useful to this quite common problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that the ticking is the power supply trying to start up, but hitting an instantaneous overcurrent limit. A good power converter will protect itself from running into a dead short, which could overheat components very quickly. Many transistor drivers have built-in desaturation protection, turning off the transistor for a set period in case the voltage across the transistor gets higher than it should be during on-state.

To do a full analysis, you'd need to develop a schematic of the circuit. Once you know what topology you're working with, and what's driving what where, you can start to debug. I'd get a scope and look at the output of the circuit while it's ticking, to observe whether any voltage at all is developing there. If the supply has multiple output rails, check them all. Then work backward through the circuit until you find the transistors and their drive circuitry. See whether the transistors are all being gated on, and if they stay in saturation during that time.

Comment: Also, to debug power supplies, one should have an isolation transformer, insulated tools, etc.